# How to add a map in dart?

Tags: game-engine, dart

I'm gonna add a 2d game's map in dart,
I use this map design by tile map.
How can i add in dart and display on html ??
Or is there any method to create game's map in dart?

Comment: Answer: Yes.  You're getting downvotes for this question because you need to try and show that you've done some research, and ask "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" - see faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask - try http://dartgamedevs.org/ for some pointers re Dart game design.

Comment: cuz I try and I can't use this map

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried, and what errors are you getting.  Maybe we can help with that?

Answer (score 1):

For historical reference, this is answered in greater detail on the dart mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/-gwxJiVNBoI